# Как получить в innerText контент только одного узла?

Tags: javascript, css

```
let selectItem = document.querySelectorAll('.select__item');
     selectItem.forEach(item => {
     item.addEventListener('click', selectChoose);
   });
```

в item попадает

```
<div class="select__item" data-id="708" data-type="city">
<span class="city-name">Белогорск</span>
<span class="city-state">Амурская область</span>
</div>
```

как мне забрать в innerText содержимое только первого span, чтобы Белогорск только попадал?

```
function selectChoose() {
      let text = this.querySelector('.city-name').innerText,
      select = this.closest('.select'),
      currentText = select.querySelector('.select__current');
      console.log(text);
      currentText.innerText = text;
      select.classList.remove('is-active');

   }
```

Comment: обратиться к элементу по классу city-name

Comment: В смысле обратиться? В переменную изначально поиск по city-name делать?

Comment: Всегда читайте документацию по методам, которые используете. В документации вы найдёте ссылки на другие методы или на аргументы, которые могут вам пригодится. Хорошая дока на [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll). Смотрите там есть "смотрите также **querySelector**". Ну а дальше выбираете Белогорск и вперёд.

Comment: в каком месте кода вам нужна эта информация? если в forEach, то item.querySelector('.city-name').innerText

Comment: Мне весь этот узел нужен в дальнейшем

Comment: @АлексейПетров вы пытаетесь это сделать: `document.querySelector('.select__item')` ? Где код selectChoose?  Где прочие select__item? В вашем примере только Белогорск будет. Не стесняйтесь показать немного больше кода, что бы вас правильно поняли.

Comment: Да, спасибо Павел item.querySelector('.city-name').innerText как бы решило мою проблему, правда не цикле, а потом смог забрать